# ODP.NET: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

First of all, I want so say I read the other questions and none of them helped me.

The server where I'm getting this error is a Windows 2003 SP2 + .net framework 4.0 + Oracle i9 client

I have downloaded the latest ODP.NET ODAC1120320Xcopy_32bit.zip a copied these dll out.

- oci.dll
- ociw32.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- orannzsbb11.dll
- oraocci11.dll
- oraociei11.dll
- OraOps11w.dll

I've created a little app which just connects to an oracle. [link](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/connect-to-an-oracle-database-without-an-oracle-client.aspx)

And when I run this app I'm getting the The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client error.

On the download page was also written : Each 32-bit ODAC client download below supports connectivity to Oracle Database versions 9.2, 10.1, 10.2, and 11.1, and 11.2.

So I guess I should be fine with my 9i database.

I'm not sure if I should use some older ODP.NET version. One answer here on SO sugested to use version 11.1.0.6.20 which supports the .NET 2.0 but my application is written against .NET 4.0.

What can I do ?

Comment: I had this issue recently myself. The problem was caused by incompatible/older Oracle DLL's that were still on the target system. To correct the problem I had to uninstall Oracle, search and delete any stray DLLs and then do a reinstall of Oracle with the latest install package (the one you described above). There may be an easier way to deal with this conflict though, so I'm just posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: When using the XCopy download, it is a good idea to simply use the install scripts provided rather than trying to roll your own and potentially missing a step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any supported method of running an oracle client without some sort of install (the xcopy version includes a batch file for installation so the "xcopy" is a bit of a misnomer.

That said, if you're going to do something that's unsupported, you might as well go with something that WILL eventually be supported - the 100% managed provider (meaning no extra unmanaged dlls to copy) is currently in beta:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbeta-1696432.html

I am suborn to see something to the end even for just the learning experience so I'd understand if you wanted to see your current way to fruition.  The [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E15167_01/InstallODP.htm) does indicate that the application directory is in fact first in the unmanaged dll search order.  My guess is that additional dlls are needed (you are using a newer version than your linked article).  I would see which specific dlls it's loading from outside of your app directory using a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and see if you can find the equivalents from the new ODAC to copy over.